# No subscribers registered for event class between fragments in EventBus

Tags: android, android-fragments, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm trying to use the GreenRobot EventBus between two fragments, but I have still No subscribers registered for event class. In my case I have two fragments in bottom navigation bar and there is no any buttons. So I'm clicking the icon on bar and changing fragment, then from the first fragment EventBus takes string and passing to the second one.

FirstFragment(Sender):

```
private void sendLocation(String location) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new BusEvent(location));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sendLocation(location);
    Log.d("TF ", location);
}
```

SecondFragment(recipient):

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onBusEvent(BusEvent event) {
    String location = event.location;
    hourlyViewModel.location.set(location);
}


@Override
public void onAttachFragment(@NonNull Fragment childFragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Event:

```
public class BusEvent {

public String location;

public BusEvent(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
}
```

Logs:

```
    D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae414900: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xaa403f20)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
I/Choreographer: Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rome&appid=52e6ff60bba8613b4850e065dcd3d0ac&units=metric
    --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rome&appid=52e6ff60bba8613b4850e065dcd3d0ac&units=metric (432ms)
D/OkHttp: Server: openresty
    Date: Sun, 27 Jan 2019 16:10:39 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 432
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Cache-Key: /data/2.5/weather?q=rome&units=metric
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
D/OkHttp: {"coord":{"lon":12.48,"lat":41.89},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":10.28,"pressure":1003,"humidity":76,"temp_min":8,"temp_max":12},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":6.2,"deg":150},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1548604200,"sys":{"type":1,"id":6792,"message":0.0036,"country":"IT","sunrise":1548570428,"sunset":1548605946},"id":6539761,"name":"Rome","cod":200}
    <-- END HTTP (432-byte body)
D/CWR: androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@228dfe8
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class com.example.daniellachacz.weatherapp2.view.BusEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
D/TF: Rome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't call the register EventBus in your Fragment. You're trying to register the EventBus with [onAttachFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment)), but it won't be called until the fragment attached another fragment as its child. As the documentation says:

> public void onAttachFragment (Fragment childFragment) Called when a
>   fragment is attached as a child of this fragment.
>
> This is called after the attached fragment's onAttach and before the
>   attached fragment's onCreate if the fragment has not yet had a
>   previous call to onCreate.

So, you need to use [onAttached](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#onAttach(android.content.Context)) instead.

Your code should be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

or use `onStart()` and `onStop()` like in the [EventBus documentation](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: I used your idea and is still same. I put the register and unregister to the onStart and the onStop.

Comment: It's probably because your Fragment isn't always in foreground. In that case, you can move the code to `onCreateView()` and `onDestroy()`

Comment: Still same problem :/

Comment: Ohhh, it seems I'm totally wrong. Your problem isn't about register or unregister, but `@Subscribe`. You need to ensure each Fragment or activiy registered with EventBus has minimal a single method with `@Subscribe` annotation.

Comment: Ok, but I have one Subscriber and this Subscriber is still never used.

Comment: Please  attach your logcat to your question so we can found out the source of the problem.

Comment: Ok I just pasted logs. Sorry for format, but editor here is terrible.

Comment: I resolved my problem. You was right about onAttach and onDetach. The problem was created because I didn't use the Sticky. This is solution if someone needs pass data immediately.

Comment: Thank you for help.